# Iterating through N lines in a for loop before moving on to next loop

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop

I posted a question on [How to interate over N lines of a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386544/how-to-interate-over-n-lines-of-a-text-file-in-python) but I wanted to make the program more applicable to N lines (e.g. instead of having to collect two line at a time I wanted to take four or six lines at a time.

I want to turn this disp.txt :

```
116  C             0.12 -0.91  0.39    -0.40  0.31  0.85    -0.66 -0.18 -0.22
117  O             0.00 -0.02  0.00    -0.05  0.05  0.12    -0.57 -0.26 -0.29
116  C            -0.03 -0.04  0.00     0.01  0.09  0.19    -0.71 -0.21 -0.26
117  O            -0.14  0.88 -0.45     0.47 -0.33 -0.79     0.57  0.16  0.19
```

To this:

```
vibration 1
0.12  -0.91  0.39
0.0  -0.02  0.0
vibration 2
-0.4  0.31  0.85
-0.05  0.05  0.12
vibration 3
-0.66  -0.18  -0.22
-0.57  -0.26  -0.29
vibration 4 
-0.03 -0.04 0.00 
-0.14 0.88 -0.45
vibration 5 ...
```

Below is what I have so far

```
vibration = 1
with open('disp1.txt','r') as f, open('disp2.txt', 'w') as out:

 while True:
  next_lines = list(islice(f,2))
  m = next_lines
  for i in m:
   s = i.strip().split('\n')
   for j in s:
    p = j.split()
    v = len(p)
    for u in range(2,5,3):
     out.write('vibration {}\n'.format(vibration))
     out.write(' '.join(p[u:u+3])+'\n')
     vibration += 1
    for x in range(5,8,3):
     out.write(' '.join(p[x:x+3])+'\n')
    for y in range(8,11,3):
      out.write(' '.join(p[y:y+3])+'\n')
  if not next_lines:
   break
```

Which is showing this:

```
vibration 1
0.12 -0.91 0.39
-0.40 0.31 0.85
-0.66 -0.18 -0.22
vibration 2
0.00 -0.02 0.00
-0.05 0.05 0.12
-0.57 -0.26 -0.29
vibration 3
-0.03 -0.04 0.00
0.01 0.09 0.19
-0.71 -0.21 -0.26
vibration 4
-0.14 0.88 -0.45
0.47 -0.33 -0.79
0.57 0.16 0.19
```

So it's reading across the page instead of reading the first two lines of first three columns of numbers and then proceeding to the next set of three and so on.
By using the isplice it reads two lines at a time but for reasons I don't understand both lines are not passed through the first loop (for u in range(2,5,3):) before moving onto the next one (for x in range(5,8,3):)
Instead each line is put through each of the loops. 
Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: But 0.12 -0.91  0.39    -0.40  0.31  0.85    -0.66 -0.18 -0.22 is one line!

Comment: Also, try using this: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Did my answer work? If so, please mark it as correct (green check).

Comment: Hi Dani, since I have six vibrations but what you showed me prints out three then I would have to repeat what you wrote three more times right? If that's the case, I'm trying to avoid having to manually do this for each different number of vibrations I have.

Comment: Is your goal to have one print statement?

Comment: My goal was to have an output file listing all the vibrations.

Comment: So why is more than one print bad? Anyhow, I'll change it later.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
def group(lst, size = 3):
    """
    returns a list of lists where the inner lists are at most
    of length size

    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    group(list, int) -> list<list>
    """
    return [lst[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(lst), size)]

def get_vibrations(lines):
    for vibration in zip(*[group(line) for line in lines]):
        yield '\n'.join(' '.join(v) for v in vibration)

def main(n):
    with open('in.txt', 'r') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
        i = 0
        for line in fin:
            line = line.strip().split()[2:]
            vibrations = [line] + [fin.readline().strip().split()[2:] for _ in range(n - 1)]

            # write each vibration to the file
            for i, v in enumerate(get_vibrations(vibrations), start = i + 1):
                fout.write('vibration {}\n{}\n'.format(i, v))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(4) # the number of lines per vibration

# Input
116  C             0.12 -0.91  0.39    -0.40  0.31  0.85    -0.66 -0.18 -0.22
117  O             0.00 -0.02  0.00    -0.05  0.05  0.12    -0.57 -0.26 -0.29
116  C            -0.03 -0.04  0.00     0.01  0.09  0.19    -0.71 -0.21 -0.26
117  O            -0.14  0.88 -0.45     0.47 -0.33 -0.79     0.57  0.16  0.19
116  C             0.26 -0.40 -0.83     0.26  0.31  0.25     0.33  0.71 -0.51
117  O            -0.19 -0.39 -0.36    -0.40  0.87  0.49     0.11  0.26 -0.57
116  C            -0.35  0.27  0.79    -0.03 -0.71 -0.18     0.93 -0.89 -0.81
117  O            -0.84  0.99  0.38    -0.27 -0.33  0.55     0.31  0.99 -0.18
116  C             0.76 -0.77  0.71     0.19 -0.39  0.46     0.30 -0.15  0.71
117  O            -0.97  0.31  0.58    -0.42  0.16 -0.33    -0.39 -0.17 -0.54

# Output
vibration 1
0.12 -0.91 0.39
0.00 -0.02 0.00
-0.03 -0.04 0.00
-0.14 0.88 -0.45
vibration 2
-0.40 0.31 0.85
-0.05 0.05 0.12
0.01 0.09 0.19
0.47 -0.33 -0.79
vibration 3
-0.66 -0.18 -0.22
-0.57 -0.26 -0.29
-0.71 -0.21 -0.26
0.57 0.16 0.19
vibration 4
0.26 -0.40 -0.83
-0.19 -0.39 -0.36
-0.35 0.27 0.79
-0.84 0.99 0.38
vibration 5
0.26 0.31 0.25
-0.40 0.87 0.49
-0.03 -0.71 -0.18
-0.27 -0.33 0.55
vibration 6
0.33 0.71 -0.51
0.11 0.26 -0.57
0.93 -0.89 -0.81
0.31 0.99 -0.18
```

If you also want to allow for not enough lines then you can add

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

And change to this

```
def get_vibrations(lines):
    for vibration in zip_longest(*[group(line) for line in lines], fillvalue = ['null']):
        yield '\n'.join(' '.join(v) for v in vibration)

# Outputs | added to above output
vibration 7
0.76 -0.77 0.71
-0.97 0.31 0.58
null
null
vibration 8
0.19 -0.39 0.46
-0.42 0.16 -0.33
null
null
vibration 9
0.30 -0.15 0.71
-0.39 -0.17 -0.54
null
null
```

Comment: When I run your script with number of lines per vibration as two I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check", line 29, in <module>
    main(2) # the number of lines per vibration
  File "check", line 22, in main
    vibrations = [line] + [fin.readline().strip().split()[2:] for _ in range(n - 1)]
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: I'm gonna go through your script see if I can understand it better thank you.

Comment: That's strange, I don't get any errors. What python version are you using, 3? Did you try just my code or try implement it into yours first?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want to be able to choose how many lines per vibration or should it always be 2?

Comment: Hello Steven, Sorry for the delay. I had been away. I want to be able to chose as many lines as I want per vibration. I tried your code and try to implement it in mine and I got the same error when I was using version 2.3. But I didn't get any errors when I used version 3 based on your comment.

Comment: In the part that says for _ in range (n-1) which does that not have to be indented like for _ in range (n-1): and also what does the underscore represent?

Comment: the `_` is a pythonic way of representing that we don't care what the value is. I don't need to give it a meaningful variable name. I could just as easily use `x` instead. [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is what I've used there. If you want to use python 2 then see if replacing `fin.readline().strip()...` with `next(fin).strip()...` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
info = '''0.12 -0.91  0.39    -0.40  0.31  0.85    -0.66 -0.18 -0.22    0.00 -0.02  0.00    -0.05  0.05  0.12    -0.57 -0.26 -0.29    -0.03 -0.04  0.00    0.01  0.09  0.19    -0.71 -0.21 -0.26    -0.14  0.88 -0.45    0.47 -0.33 -0.79     0.57  0.16  0.19'''

new_list_1 = info.split('    ')
vib_1 = new_list_1[0] + '\n' + new_list_1[3]
vib_1 = 'vibration 1' + '\n' + vib_1
print vib_1

new_list_2 = info.split('    ')
vib_2 = new_list_2[1] + '\n' + new_list_2[4]
vib_2 = 'vibration 2' + '\n' + vib_2
print vib_2

new_list_3 = info.split('    ')
vib_3 = new_list_3[2] + '\n' + new_list_3[5]
vib_3 = 'vibration 3' + '\n' + vib_3
print vib_3
```